# Insert dropdown value into text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I will need to use Javascript to get this to work. Heres is my drop down menu

```
<select id="Codes" name="CODEOPTION">
    <option value="A">Option A</option>
    <option value="B">Option B</option>
    <option value="C">Option C</option>
    <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>
```

So when the user selects a drop down option the value would feed into this text field:

```
<input type="text" name="CODES" value="">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/gojwgbLv/

Comment: @tymeJV Your answer was perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `change` event

```
$("#Codes").change(function() {
    $("input[name=CODES]").val(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery it would be this:

```
$('#Codes').change(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#Codes").change(function(){               
    var temp=$(this).val();
    $("input[name='CODES']").val(temp);                
});
```

Have a look at this [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/16ngyg2v/) example for better understanding.